# How to get top panel drop downs to become dark mode?

Tags: themes

I got my system to be in darkmode, except for the meta menu, calendar, system tray and power options from the top panel. Also, every app is now dark mode, except for system-settings its child windows.

I've used 'prefer dark mode' in system settings and this [this repo](https://github.com/veyselerden/elementaryos-dark-theme-enabler-script). to get to where what's it at now. Anyone know how I can fix this?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using **elementary tweaks** to archieve dark mode, which don't have problem for dropdown menu of wingpanel.

> elementary tweaks
>
> https://github.com/elementary-tweaks/elementary-tweaks

For System Settings, dark mode doesn't apply after recent upate. Fix can be found below.

https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/gxhsi9/slowly_losing_dark_theme_with_each_update/

> Replace the file at
>
> `/usr/share/dbus-1/interfaces/io.elementary.pantheon.AccountsService.xml`
>
> with the contents of
>
> https://github.com/elementary/default-settings/blob/master/accountsservice/io.elementary.pantheon.AccountsService.xml
>
> and change the value of `PrefersColorScheme` property to `1`.

Comment: strange, I used tweak tools too for dark mode, but the drop downs are very mich light mode for me.